# Error "field not Found" : (espacios) al compilar un informe Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Me aparece un error cuando intento compilar mi aplicacion java ...

```js
INFORMACIÓN: Creating DynamicJasperDesign
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. Field not found : 
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)
```

... donde no indica que campo es .. al hacer Debug veo que estan los campos, las columnas etc... que puede ser este error????

Comment: Por favor, cual el el código que estas compilando?

Comment: Ya lo solucione muchas gracias.... ocurrio que estoy leyendo los datos de un fichero JSON, y cargaba la primera linea del fichero que es "{" y eso es lo que da el error.. .. de todas formas me ha aparecido otro error al seguir con la compilacion del jrxml . lo pongo a cotinuacion

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione muchas gracias.... ocurrio que estoy leyendo los datos de un fichero JSON, y cargaba la primera linea del fichero que es "{" y eso es lo que da el error.. .. de todas formas me ha aparecido otro error al seguir con la compilacion del jrxml ..
Pero ahora me da el siguiente error....

```
INFORMACIÓN: Done generating JasperReport for design with name: DJR_3610
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : fecha
```

dandome el error indicado ..." Error retrieving field value from bean : fecha"

Alguna idea??... poco a poco me voy acercando a compilar correctamente mi rjxml ... a ver !!!

Comment: Si esto no es una respuesta no lo debes colocar en esta zona, edita tu pregunta y ahí agrega lo que haga falta

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559804/net-sf-jasperreports-engine-jrexception-error-retrieving-field-value-from-bean

Comment: perdon por lo se poner la resuesta ahi .. el caso es que estoy con el siguiente peldaño de este programa .....  si quereis verlo lo tengo como "Fallo al descomponer en registro un fichero JSON para imprimir informe Jasper report" por si pudierais ayudarme .... gracias